# PythonAnywhere Edits from Python (Such as VS Code)

Tags: python, mysql, pythonanywhere

I'm struggling to find a way to edit my PythonAnywhere MYSql database from my vscode script. I've tried multiple ways to do thus far and they have all failed. I believe that I successfully connected to my database using this: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/

I followed the part where it says "From Python Code". I completed that and my code runs with no errors, but this code just establishes a connection. I'm unsure of how I would start making edits/pulls from the database. For example, I would like to just run a select all from a random table, however I don't know how to get to this point. Any help or advice here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you see the comment `# Do stuff` in the example, just before `connection.close()`? That is where your code to query the database goes. You say that your code establish connection, so I assume you have paid account.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate something like this example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html I'm unsure how to replicate this however.

Comment: What **exactly** is unclear? in pythonanywhere example the connection name is well `connection`. In the MySQL example the connection name is `conn`. You can use the example code from mysql.com, just rename `cnx` to connection` or rename `connection` to `cnx`